# Regex, string is a combination of whitelisted characters and doesn't contain any in blacklist

Tags: javascript, regex, qml

1) How to regex validate user input to contain any combination of characters from group A and to not contain any characters from another group D?
2) Also check string length is between 2 and 255

In other words, for all string characters: A AND NOT D.

I receive two groups of characters (whitelist and blacklist) from a server and need to validate user input based on those. I cannot affect the design and must live with it. I also must use regex because of other design restrictions.

Here's what I've got so far (not working at all):

`/^(?![23]+)[0-9]{2,255}$/`

**23** would be the blacklist of characters for simplicity
**0-9** would be the whitelist of characters for simplicity

Some examples:

**3014567890** --> fail, 3 is present
**0145678902** --> fail, 2 is present
**0123456789** --> fail, 2 and 3 are present
**014567890** --> ok
**88774411489** --> ok
**5** --> fail, not enough characters
**1abc** --> fail, abc illegal chars
**ab1c** --> fail, abc illegal chars
**abc1** --> fail, abc illegal chars

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you build `/^[01456789]{2,255}$/` ?

Comment: Are **23** really supposed to be both in the blacklist **and** the whitelist?

Comment: zeroflagL: unfortunately that can be possible :). Hmm, I think I could manually modify whitelist to exclude blacklist chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nearly there, the lookahead assertion needs some work:

```
/^(?!.*[23])[0-9]{2,255}$/
```

That way, the regex within the negative lookahead matches if there is (at least) one `2` or `3` anywhere in the string (i. e., after any number of characters (`.*`)), causing the assertion to fail.

In this (apparently) simplified example, you could of course just have used  `/^[014-9]{2,255}$/`.

Comment: Thank you sir, I also like the other possibility.